# Do only if line of text file is not empty

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I want to output only if the line of the script is not empty.
I have seen some solutions but they used variables for the line and I dont want to do that.

My Sciprt:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/home/user/scripte/schuelerListe.txt"
while IFS=: read -r vn nn kl
do
    printf 'Vorname: %s, Nachname: %s, Klasse: %s\n' "$vn" "$nn" "$kl"
done <"$input"
```

The txt-file:

```
Pyka:Johannes:IT11FS
Gerber:Dennis:IT11FS
Ewender:Laura:IT11FS

Manfred:Rolf:IT11FA
Mammensohn:Friedl:IT11FA
Bittl:Erwin:IT11FA

Wanzinger:Johanna:IT11SE
Summer:Maximilian:IT11SE
Schmied:Burkhard:IT11SE
```

Expected output:

```
Vorname: Pyka, Nachname: Joahnnes, Klasse: IT11FS
...
Vorname: Ewender, Nachanem: Laura, Klasse: IT11FS

Vorname: Manfred, Nachname: Rolf, Klasse: IT11FS
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. filter out the empty lines:

   ```sh
   grep . "$input" | while IFS=: read -r vn nn kl
   do
       printf 'Vorname: %s, Nachname: %s, Klasse: %s\n' "$vn" "$nn" "$kl"
   done
   ```
2. test the variables for emptiness:

   ```sh
   while IFS=: read -r vn nn kl
   do
       if [[ -n $vn && -n $nn && -n $kl ]]
       then
           printf 'Vorname: %s, Nachname: %s, Klasse: %s\n' "$vn" "$nn" "$kl"
       fi
   done
   ```
3. read the fields into an array:

   ```sh
   while IFS=: read -ra fields
   do
       if (( ${#fields[*]} != 0 ))
       then
           printf 'Vorname: %s, Nachname: %s, Klasse: %s\n' "${fields[@]}"
       fi
   done
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```sh
awk -F: 'NF == 3 {
   printf "Vorname: %s, Nachname: %s, Klasse: %s\n", $1, $2, $3
}' file
```

```
Vorname: Pyka, Nachname: Johannes, Klasse: IT11FS
Vorname: Gerber, Nachname: Dennis, Klasse: IT11FS
Vorname: Ewender, Nachname: Laura, Klasse: IT11FS
Vorname: Manfred, Nachname: Rolf, Klasse: IT11FA
Vorname: Mammensohn, Nachname: Friedl, Klasse: IT11FA
Vorname: Bittl, Nachname: Erwin, Klasse: IT11FA
Vorname: Wanzinger, Nachname: Johanna, Klasse: IT11SE
Vorname: Summer, Nachname: Maximilian, Klasse: IT11SE
Vorname: Schmied, Nachname: Burkhard, Klasse: IT11SE
```

Comment: If I use your solution, the output is: Vorname: Pyka:Johannes:IT11FS, Nachname: Pyka:Johannes:IT11FS, Klasse: Pyka:Johannes:IT11FS and this for every line of the file, even multiple times!

Comment: I have shown generated output in this answer which prints columns for each non-blank line. Are you not getting same output?